# stylesheet for print output

Tags: feature-request, design

Please provide stylesheet for printing a post not using fixed width.

Printing should not use fixed width and truncate on the right, but have a free "flow" of text content adjusting itself to page width.
Portrait and landscape formats should both come out well, then.

Comment: As an alternative, try http://www.stackprinter.com/

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your feature request is about? Do you want print CSS for Stack Overflow posts?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider making your own css file to print the page?

Comment: While I personally never print questions, I see how a [`@media print` stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) would be useful (and not that hard to implement).