# A possible bug: The right margin of printed SE content is way too large

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, google-chrome, printing

I am viewing a Stack Exchange question in Chrome on a Windows machine.  If I now click on "Print...", I obtain the following preview:

[image]

Visually, there appears to be way too much white space to the right of the question, and this continues down through the comments and answers of this question.  In this format, just this single question and a few short comments and answers require seven pages to print.

Multiple other meta.se questions have noted this margin issue (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304096/comments-and-answers-have-huge-right-margins-when-printed), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314194/printing-correctly-posts-small-margins), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317013/css-bug-with-printing-site-pages-now-with-100-more-suggested-fix-included), and possibly [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172313/stylesheet-for-print-output) for examples), and the fix seems plausibly trivial (possibly just changing several widths to "auto" in the relevant CSS).

So my question is, what hope do we have that this may be corrected in the near future?

P.S.  For interested users, there are great SE-developed tools to download SE content.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65750/offline-copy-of-my-stackoverflow-questions) for a description of these.  I see these as complementary to, not a replacement for, well-formatted printing directly from the primary landing page.

Comment: @Kodos Thanks for this additional link; I just updated my question to include it as well.  Complaints regarding this bug appear to go back to at least December 2017, and the repair looks very simple.  Is there any way to vault it into the field of vision of a SE developer who could make the necessary edit?

Comment: Unfortunately all you can really do is upvote any questions/answers related to this problem and edit them to fix issues (which bumps them up in the question list so someone will notice). I've noticed that the developers sometimes go on a fixing spree so I hope this will be one of the things they fix soon.

Comment: I added an answer to the question I linked to. It includes the CSS fix that the SE developers need to implement as well as some javascript code which you can copy to your bookmark toolbar and run it on any page to apply the fix.

Comment: Please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).

Comment: Thanks for these additional comments, etc.  I've taken the step of notifying SE via their contact page, referencing this question and the one linked at the top of the page which contains Kodos's excellent answer.